# What's wrong with my method to resize an image while keeping the same aspect ration?

Tags: c#, image

My goal is to resize an image if it's over a certain height or width, keeping the same aspect ratio.  Here's what I've got so far:

```
    static public Stream ScaleImage(HttpPostedFileBase imageFile)
    {
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
        var maxWidth = 500;
        var maxHeight = 500;
        var image = Image.FromStream(imageFile.InputStream, true, true);

        if (image.Width > maxWidth || image.Height > maxHeight)
        {
            // something in here is broken
            var ratioX = (double)maxWidth / image.Width;
            var ratioY = (double)maxHeight / image.Height;
            var ratio = Math.Min(ratioX, ratioY);

            var newWidth = (int)(image.Width * ratio);
            var newHeight = (int)(image.Height * ratio);

            var newImage = new Bitmap(image, newWidth, newHeight);
            Graphics.FromImage(newImage).DrawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(newImage);

            bmp.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            stream.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            // this works fine
            image.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            stream.Close();
        }
        return stream;
    }
```

If the image is under the max sizes, then it works fine.  But if it needs to be resized, then for some reason that I can't spot, the Stream that is returned is full of errors:

[image]

Comment: Why are you returning a closed stream?

Comment: The API to which I need to send the image, and over which I have no control, requires a stream.  But that's not really the point, as saving to a Stream works just fine when not re-sizing.

Comment: If you say so. I've just encountered the same error with an image that didn't need to be resized. Before `stream.Close()` is called, there aren't any ObjectDisposedException errors, but after it's called, they're there. I did need to call `stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);` for the stream to then become usable, but it works.

Comment: ok - that's worth noting.  How did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I've replaced the bottom part of the code with this, and it's working for me:

```
        bmp.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
    else
    {
        image.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    return stream;
}
```

Closing the MemoryStream causes the Disposed errors you've been seeing. I'm not sure why the second method would appear to work fine.

Comment: still getting the same error.  I'm taking an entirely different approach. Thanks for the help.